# Internet explorer has stopped working When I print preview my web page that has highchart

Tags: internet-explorer, printing, preview, mvc

When I print preview a web page that I used highchart component, I encountered an error that is "Internet explorer has stopped working...". This problem is only happening when print preview. At the moment I am using IE 11. IE 9 version is working properly. I don't know how it works in IE 11 ver.

Comment: Do you know if it works with IE11? Sounds like there is a bug, I'd email the devs

Comment: The page can be rendered by IE 11, but the problem occurs when I do print preview and print. No problem firefox, chrome, IE9

Comment: I have added the following code and it was fixed.
svg
{
    position: absolute !important;
}

Answer (score 3):

The asker managed to solve the problem, but hasn't posted it as an answer.
Copying the answer for the benefit of any other users who don't notice it...

Adding the following CSS solved the problem entirely:
`svg { position: absolute !important }`